# Are there technical reasons to prefer using logback instead of log4j?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, logback

Should new projects use logback instead of log4j as a logging framework ?

Or with other words :'Is logback better than log4j (leaving the SLF4J-'feature' of logback beside)?'

Comment: Could you expand upon why this question was closed?

Comment: This question is useful to me, voting to reopen.

Comment: How on earth is this "too localized?" An enormous number of java projects use log4j. The question of whether it should be considered "deprecated" in favor of the newer logback (whose authors seem to consider that it deprecates log4j) is relevant to a lot of people and will continue to be for some time.

Comment: Voted to reopen, but there appears to be only my one vote present.

Comment: Voted to reopen as well; I suppose its localized to "java" and that's good enough :/

Comment: Vote to reopen - this is a very valid question. Not at all too localized.

Comment: Logback is greater, faster framework for logging. http://logback.qos.ch/reasonsToSwitch.html

Comment: Useful question. Voting to reopen.

Comment: If 4 individuals have voted to reopen, why isn't it open?

Comment: And 13 years after asking, this question is more actual than ever.

Answer (score 83):

You should use SLF4J+Logback for logging.

It provides neat features like parametrized messages and (in contrast to commons-logging) a Mapped Diagnostic Context (MDC, [javadoc](http://slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/MDC.html), [documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html)).

Using SLF4J makes the logging backend exchangeable in a quite elegant way.

Additionally, SLF4J [supports bridging](http://slf4j.org/legacy.html) of other logging frameworks to the actual SLF4J implementation you'll be using so logging events from third party software will show up in your unified logs - with the exception of java.util.logging that can't be bridged the same way that other logging frameworks are.

Bridging jul is explained in the [javadocs](http://slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/bridge/SLF4JBridgeHandler.html) of SLF4JBridgeHandler.

I've had a very good experience using the SLF4J+Logback combination in several projects and LOG4J development has pretty much stalled.

SLF4J has the following remaining downsides:

- It does not support varargs to stay compatible with Java < 1.5
- It does not support using both parametrized message and an exception at the same time.
- It does not contain support for a Nested Diagnostic Context (NDC, [javadoc](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/NDC.html)) which LOG4J has.

Comment: LOL, I just received the Necromancer badge for this answer! Thanks to all voters ;) I've never expected to receive that one...

Comment: Mapped Diagnostic Context is more powerful alternative to Nested Diagnostic Context

Comment: That's not entirely true. They are actually orthogonal concepts. The MDC is a Map while the NDC is a Stack. Take a look at http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/lilith/wiki/NestedDiagnosticContext for some usage examples.

Comment: I never found out why MDC and NDC are called what they are called instead of something easier to memorize.  Sigh.

Comment: Yep, same with me. On the other hand, what would be a better name?

Comment: But why use NDC, is there actually a need for it,whyu not simply log an INFO message w/ that context message ?

Comment: I've ranted a bit about how I'd like to see NDC implemented in SLF4J over in the Lilith Wiki: http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/lilith/wiki/NestedDiagnosticContext

Comment: @Huxi, "Map" and "Stack" perhaps?

Comment: @mP. the code doing the log statement may not know the information put on the NDC.

Answer (score 23):

The author (of both Logback and Log4j) has a list of reasons to change at http://logback.qos.ch/reasonsToSwitch.html.

Here are a few that stuck out at me;

- **Faster implementation**

  Based on our previous work on log4j,
  logback internals have been
  re-written to perform about ten times
  faster on certain critical execution
  paths. Not only are logback
  components faster, they have a
  smaller memory footprint as well.
- **Automatic reloading of configuration
  files**

  Logback-classic can automatically
  reload its configuration file upon
  modification. The scanning process is
  both fast and safe as it does not
  involve the creation of a separate
  thread for scanning. This technical
  subtlety ensures that logback plays
  well within application servers and
  more generally within the JEE
  environment.
- **Stack traces with packaging data**

  When logback prints an exception, the
  stack trace will include packaging
  data. Here is a sample stack trace
  generated by the logback-demo
  web-application.

  14:28:48.835 [btpool0-7] INFO 
  c.q.l.demo.prime.PrimeAction - 99 is
  not a valid value
  java.lang.Exception: 99 is invalid
  at
  ch.qos.logback.demo.prime.PrimeAction.execute(PrimeAction.java:28)
  [classes/:na]   at
  org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
  [struts-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]   at
  org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
  [struts-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]   at
  org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
  [struts-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]   at
  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
  [servlet-api-2.5-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
  at
  org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:502)
  [jetty-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]   at
  ch.qos.logback.demo.UserServletFilter.doFilter(UserServletFilter.java:44)
  [classes/:na]   at
  org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1115)
  [jetty-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]   at
  org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:361)
  [jetty-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]   at
  org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:417)
  [jetty-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]   at
  org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
  [jetty-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]

  From the above, you can recognize
  that the application is using Struts
  version 1.2.9 and was deployed under
  jetty version 6.1.12. Thus, stack
  traces will quickly inform the reader
  about the classes invervening in the
  exception but also the package and
  package versions they belong to. When
  your customers send you a stack
  trace, as a developer you will no
  longer need to ask them to send you
  information about the versions of
  packages they are using. The
  information will be part of the stack
  trace. See "%xThrowable" conversion
  word for details.

  This feature can be quite helpful to
  the point that some users mistakenly
  consider it a feature of their IDE.
- **Automatic removal of old log archives**

  By setting the maxHistory property of
  TimeBasedRollingPolicy or
  SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP, you can
  control the maximum number of
  archived files. If your rolling
  policy calls for monthly rollover and
  you wish to keep one year's worth of
  logs, simply set the maxHistory
  property to 12. Archived log files
  older than 12 months will be
  automatically removed.

There may be a bias there, but the same guy did write both frameworks and if he is saying use Logback over Log4j he's probably worth listening to.

Comment: Note that the author has personal reasons for wanting people to switch, so the list is not completely unbiased.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen What personal reasons? It is an open source project.

Comment: It is a long story. I suggest you open a new question if you really want to know.

Comment: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/logging-log4j-dev/200704.mbox/%3C20070404194653.9F87F36CC1@mail.qos.ch%3E

Now it's clear that log4j was taken over by incompetent people and the consequences are disastrous.

Comment: @DanubianSailor That sounds to me more that log4j 1.3 was forked by its original author (who essentially left the project) and then renamed to logback, than it was taken over.  It is hinted that this was due to losing a vote, which presumably was whether to go this way or not.   The question then is why so much work had been done, if the team was not in agreement about it?   That said, log4j2 is not disasterous as such.

Answer (score 10):

I would use slf4j for logging in all cases.  This allow you to choose which actual logging backend you want to use, at deploy time instead of code time.

This has proven to be very valuable to me.  It allows me to use log4j in old JVM's, and logback in 1.5+ JVM's, and also java.util.logging if needed.

Comment: Now many moons later I am not sure that the underlying thought that logging is an invisible friend walking next to your code is right.  This was inspired by a talk describing https://github.com/EqualExperts/opslogger.

Answer (score 2):

Logback more Java EE aware:
in general (from code to documentation) it’s keeping in mind containers – how multiple apps coexist, how class loaders implemented etc. Contexts for loggers, JNDI, JMX configuration included etc.

from developer prospective almost same, Logback adds 
Parameterized logging (no need to use if(logger.isDebugEnabled()) to avoid string concatenation overhead )

Log4j – only giant plus is old JVM support, small (IMO) 
NDC (Logback only MDC), some extensions. For example I wrote extension for configureAndWatch for Log4j, no such thing for Logback

Answer (score 1):

the original log4j and logback were designed and implemented by the same guy.

several open source tools have used SLF4J. I don't see any significant deficiencies in this tool. So unless you have a lot extensions to log4j in your codebase, I would go ahead with logback.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that your decision should come down to the same one it would if you were deciding between using log4j or Jakarta Commons Logging - are you developing a library which will be included in other applications? If so, then it doesn't seem fair to force users of your library to also use your logging library of choice.

If the answer is no, I would just go with what is simpler to add and what you are more comfortable with. Sounds like logback is just as extensible and reliable as log4j, so if you're comfortable using it, go ahead.

Comment: If you are developing a library, use slf4j, as it can use any backend without the downsides of commmons-logging.  If you are writing an app use slf4j so you can use logback.

Answer (score -3):

I'm not familiar with SLF4J, and I've only taken a brief look at logback, but two things come to mind.

First, why are you excluding a tool from examination? I think it's important to keep an open mind and examine all possibilities to choose the best one.

Second, I think that in some projects one tool is a better than another tool, and the opposite might be true in a different project. I don't think that one tool is always better than another tool. There is, after all, **no silver bullet**.

To answer your question - Yes and no. It depends on the project, and how familiar the team is with one tool. I wouldn't say "don't use log4j" if the entire team is very comfortable with it, it meets all the needs, and logback doesn't offer anything that we need to complete the task.

Comment: SLF4J is a facade that logback uses. I leaving nothing beside. It is 'feature'.

Comment: Ah. Thanks for clarifying, but the main points of my answer still do apply.

Comment: Wow! Talk about ambiguous... replace `log4j` and `logback` in this answer for any two libraries, languages, IDEs, etc. and see the result! its amazing! :D