# What Log4j alternative logging libraries are available?

Tags: java, logging

What logging libraries do you recommend as alternatives to [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/)?  Do these libraries work with Spring and Hibernate?  Are they compatible with [Slf4j](http://slf4j.org/) or [Jakarta Commons Logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/)?

Comment: Subjective and argumentative? Really?

Comment: Does anybody use a logging framework other than Log4j and Logback?

Comment: Why the vote to close?  This is hardly a subjective question. I'm asking for a factual list of Java logging libraries that work with Spring and Hibernate. I didn't even ask people to specify the relative strengths or merits of these libraries, let alone ask for the weaknesses of Log4j. How can this be considered subjective and argumentative?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

slf4j allows you to use just about all the other logging frameworks at once. Juli, Commons, Log4j etc.. As an output framework to use with slf4j instead of Log4j, I would suggest Logback
http://logback.qos.ch/ which is written and maintained by the creator of Log4j.

Comment: Can Spring and Hibernate use slf4j with Logback instead of Commons Logging with Log4j?

Comment: Yes, we use Spring + SLF4J + Logback in Red5

Comment: I'm sure this is more info than you need and it is Red5 specific, but it may help explain what to do:
http://www.red5.org/wiki/Documentation/Tutorials/LoggingSetup

Comment: Judging from the number of votes for this answer and the absence of any other specific responses, it seems that the combination of slf4j and Logback is now the dominant alternative to Log4j.

Comment: @Mondain: I learned that in order to Commons Logging with SLF4J, Spring 2.5.6 requires bridging jarfile `jcl-over-slf4j.jar`.  See http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#jcl-over-slf4j.

Comment: @Mondain: Started using SLF4J and Logback and so far happy with the combination!

Comment: @Mondain: Looks like many other Stack Overflow users agree with you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178836/should-new-projects-use-logback-instead-of-log4j.

Answer (score 3):

[Java Source](http://java-source.net) publishes a list of [open source logging libraries](http://java-source.net/open-source/logging).