# Logging frameworks, formats and protocols available on the market?

Tags: logging

I need to complete an academic work by citing and possibly comparing the available logging frameworks, formats (and *protocols*) available in Internet, both open and proprietary.

My work deeply covers **Syslog 2009** protocol, and I also mention Apache logging frameworks such as log4net, log4j, log4php, log4cxx. Reference is also to the classic Syslog protocol and syslog-ng service.

Now I would like to know:

1. What other frameworks do you know? Both open source and proprietary, I repeat. I read about an IBM proprietary framework
2. Where can I find sample log entries for each known logging format. I want to prove the heterogeneity of logging formats in applications
3. If Syslog BSD (RFC 3164) and Syslog 2009 (RFC 5424) are the only logging formats/protocols standardized by IETF

Thank you in advance

[Add] Well... no one else replied. Giving bounty and mark to the only answerer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LogBack @ http://logback.qos.ch/ is the best choice in my opinion. Log4j is legacy. Java also comes with native Logging feature from 1.4 onwards I believe. more info can be found at http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2002/06/19/log.html

You can find some comparission here http://www.java-logging.com/comparison/

Comment: Can you answer two more quick questions? Does LogBack support Syslog 2009? I did a quick search, but found nothing yet, I'll try tomorrow. Second, why in your opinion is LogBack the best choice for Java projects? I care about that ;)

Comment: Instead of repeating I would direct you to 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178836/should-new-projects-use-logback-instead-of-log4j and 2) http://logback.qos.ch/10reasons.ppt