What is the slf4j equivalent of logger.getAppender?
I'm trying to change a codebase from using log4j to slf4j. We have a log4j.xml with appenders like this
    <appender name="DefaultAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Threshold" value="OFF"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-4r [%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS}] %-5p %c %x - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

I am changing all of our instances of org.apache.log4j.Logger to org.slf4j.Logger, but some classes have lines like this...
AppenderSkeleton consoleAppender = (AppenderSkeleton) logger.getAppender("DefaultAppender")
and the getAppender function doesn't exist on the slf4j Logger class.
How do I achieve the same result in slf4j?

Your title might be cut off BTW - it reads "What is the slf4j equivelant of" and nothing else

which logging backend are you using behind the SLF4J api?

@Progman sorry, I don't understand the question

@ChrisA SLF4J is only a facade/API, it does not do the actual logging. You have to check what logging backend you are using behind the SLF4J api and look for the documentation of that library.

@Progman I'm implementing slf4j in a project which currently uses log4j so I guess it's log4j

@Progman Yes that seems to answer my question. So if it is still log4j doing the actual logging, what purpose is slf4j actually serving?

@ChrisA It's a facade for logging, which is independent of the logging engine in the background. See other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34797987/understanding-logback-and-slf4j
